# Kentico Smart Search for application with multiple sites

Tags: kentico

I am having quite the difficulty.  on our company site https://temp-quitlogixbase.quitlogix.org I had set up the Smart Search functionality.  setting up indexes for each of the sites with in the application

(i.e.

https://colorado.quitlogix.org https://arkansas.quitlogix.orghttps://idaho.quitlogix.org

)

I even made sure to limit each site to the index meant for it.  the problem is that the smart search results, either changes for each site, or if I include multipule indexes it gives me all the results for all the indexes, not just for the site I am working with.  can some one help as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you assigned sites to each of the indexes? If so, remove the sites you don't want on either of the indexes.

Comment: Yes I agree with @BrendenKehren, please check if your indexes are appropriately assigned to the correct site and no one is assigned haphazardly. I never encountered this. Secondly, are you suing out of the box search or getting results through a custom code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, it sounds like you want each site's search to work independently so that - e.g. - Idaho results are not served on the Colorado search results.

To do this, you'll have (and sounds like you do) a SmartSearch index set up for each site with the allowed content in the index limited to the site in question.

What I would look at is the template your using for the search results.  It looks *very* similar on the three sites you've listed, which makes me think that they are the same template.  If that is the case and you're using a web part for the search results, you'll need a macro or some other logic to tell the page which index to look at.The template is effectively global, so each time you set the index on the **Smart search results** web part, it will override the previous value, even if you're switching between sites.

A way to do the switching can be to set the **Indexes** field to something like the following macro:

```
{% if (CurrentSite.CodeName == "QuitLogix_Arkansas") { "ArkansasSiteIndex" } else if(CurrentSite.CodeName == "QuitLogix_Colorado") { "ColoradoSiteIndex" } else {"IdahoSiteIndex"} @%}
```

If you've done all that or are using separate templates, you will not need that. Other options can include using multiple **Smart search results** web parts with their set the visibility based upon the current site or by having a different template for each sub-domain.

Comment: I think you won't have to do all this if the websites are assigned correctly to sites and Smart search web part. We have multi tenant website settings with 25+ websites and never encountered this.

Comment: You're missing a point of my suggestions @chetan-samara; if the sites are using the same template (which these look to be doing given the layouts of the links provided by the OP), then you will have an issue.  Our multi-tenant sites - typically use different templates so this is never an issue.  From my experience, when they're the same template you need to let Kentico know which index to use.  All of the above options are valid approaches I have working in various live projects.

Comment: I guess you don't have to because if you're using a web part like smart search you can easily pick an index from there. Secondly, allow me disagree but sharing same templates across website is a bad choice from software engineering practices. I am not saying that it will not work what I am  saying is that it's an inappropriate choice. I am okay if you disagree. Thanks

Comment: Just because you disagree Chetan, doesn't mean Matt's answer is wrong.

Comment: mnield,  your assumptions about the layout is correct.  this was actually developed by a third party, and i guess using one template was for ease of modification.   I was hired on due to my angular knowledge to fix the items the 3rd party got wrong, and to maintain / implement new items.

Comment: I will try to use your segestion,  I guess I was mostly unsure as to the syntax of the properties.

Comment: Well, mnield had the correct answer for my situation.  Thanks.  I had to go the visibility route since the index route was not quite working.

Comment: I’m glad this helped, Dan. If you could mark it as the correct answer, that might also help other find the answer if they need it.  Also, if you have more Kentico questions, you can look at devnet.kentico.com (which links to stackoverflow)

Comment: @BrendenKehren _ i am not saying the answer is wrong you need to read comments carefully to make that. This is a public forum and we all can disagree in a respectful way. Right Brenden? Read this what I wrote before make any assumptions Brenden "I am not saying that it will not work what I am saying is that it's an inappropriate choice. I am okay if you disagree. Thanks"

Comment: @BrendenKehren - I would still say as software best practice it's not an appropriate choice when dealing with many websites. And please read carefully before you jump to any assumption it's inappropriate not incorrect.

Comment: @DanMain - Would you like to share your code of why assigning a website was not working?

Comment: Chetan based on you downvoting the answer, it's assumed you don't approve of the answer or the answer is not right.  I understand opinions but clearly the OP approved the answer and if you read the rest of the questions you'll see this is that the OP wants/needs. For a multi site instance with similar branding we use this approach all the time.

Comment: I'm fine with people disagreeing and don't want to really get drawn into a huge conversation about it. We’re all entitled to a view on the approaches we take in the solutions that we build. As with Brenden, we use templates across sites with the same brand for consistency. To me, that is why you can use templates across sites. With that viewpoint, I would disagree with you, Chetan that it is a poor choice in this instance. I agree that if the sites were for multitenancy sites, it would be inappropriate to share them. The point is, Dan has a route forward and can get on with his day job :)

Comment: Chetan, My If then statment for assigning the index was not working

{% if (CurrentSite.CodeName=="Site-A") { "Site-Index-A" }  #%}

,  but the logic to make the Smart Search Result visible/hidden did

{% if (CurrentSite.CodeName=="Site-A") { true } else { false } #%}

Still new to Kentico Macros, so not quite comfortable with them yet.